# Allow multiple URI parameters through regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm pretty close from what I want to achieve.

I have this :

```
'/create-group/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)(?:/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+))?(?:(\?|&)(groupid|copyofgroup|ref)=([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+))?'
```

It allows me to restrain what URIs can be typed in and accessed, such as:

```
/create-group/123/456?groupid=789
```

In the last bit of the regex, I allow 3 parameters (groupid, copyofgroup and ref).

This is all good, but I can't figure out a way to have my preg_match validate an **infinite** number of these 3 parameters. Right now, I'm only limited to 1 instance of a parameter.

I'd like my preg_match() to accept :

```
/create-group/123/456?groupid=789&ref=101112&copyofgroup=789
```

I've tried multipliers such as `*` and `+`, but to no avail.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using regex and not `$_GET`, `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` superglobals?

Comment: @Nordenheim I'm not sure what you mean? This code is place at the top-level before fetching the relevant files. I just want to restrain what parameters can be inserted in the URI. How would $_GET superglobals help me?

Comment: Replace `[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]` with `[[:alnum:]_-]`. Characters lose their specialness inside square braces, so you don't need to escape things with backslashes, and a dash at the either end means a dash rather than a range delimiter. And character classes just make sense.

Comment: @Justin01 the tags suggest you use PHP, meaning you can `$_GET` the needed parameters from the URI string and ignore the rest instead of crutching your way through the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can add {0,3} instead of "?", at the end:

> /create-group/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)(?:/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+))?(?:(\?|&)(groupid|copyofgroup|ref)=([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)){0,3}

I tried here:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: Very interesting, don't know why I haven't thought of that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

```
'/create-group/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)(?:/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+))?(?:((\?|&)(groupid|copyofgroup|ref)=([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+))+)?'
```